# Did not understand why the following output of program in C is so

Tags: c

The program below is printing:

b 
c
d
e
f
g
h
i
j
k
l
m

l
m
n
o
p
and (5 spaces)

I don't know why it is printing so. I allocated a size of 10 chars, and wanted to see what will happen if I print it until 12. Please, help me

```
int main(){
    char *sentences = (char*) malloc(sizeof(char)*10);
    int a;

    for(a = 0; a < 12; a++){
       sentences[a] = 'b' + a;
    }

    for(a = 0; a < 12; a++){
        printf("%c", sentences[a]);
    }

    printf("\n");
    //here I should free allocated memory, to avoid memory leak 
    sentences = (char *) malloc(sizeof(char)*5);

    for(a = 0; a < 5; a++){
        sentences[a] = 'l' + a;
    }

    for (a = 0; a < 10; a++){
        printf( "%c", sentences[a]);
    }
   free(sentences);
}
```

Comment: So why do you allocate 10 but do a loop of 12?

Comment: This was one of exercises during lab sessions. It asks what are potential problems in this program, like memory leakage. Why it does not give segmentation fault?

Comment: Oh, I now see you **deliberately** invoke *undefined behaviour*. No rational answer.

Comment: Reading beyond the memory you've allocated causes undefined behaviour, which means "anything can happen". There's plenty of existing documentation about UB.

Comment: The lab or its preparational reading, should have explained. Now you should explain your understanding. https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/334822/how-do-i-ask-and-answer-homework-questions This still applies if the lab is over and you are not going to hand in our answers. Because in the described way you will have a much better learning experience and effect.

Comment: "Why it does not give segmentation fault?" because the behaviour is *undefined*. If it was **guaranteed** to give a segfault, the behaviour would be *defined* but it isn't.

Comment: Thanks. Got it. We were doing this in lab and lab is over, instructor hasn't provided solutions yet. I am just curious to know it before solutions

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you read or write past the end of allocated memory, you invoke [undefined behavior](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior).

This means you can't reliably predict the behavior of your program.  It may crash, it may generate strange results, or it may appear to work properly.  How undefined behavior manifests itself can change with a seemingly unrelated code change, such as adding an extra unused variable or adding a `printf` for debugging.

Just because you do something that *could* cause the program to crash doesn't  mean that it *will*.

Comment: Maybe explain the why... it's reading memory that wasn't allocated to the program, so it's considered "garbage", and may or may not convert to, in this case, printable ascii characters. In some cases, the memory may be protected and cause a segfault, in others your program will just read whatever data populates those memory addresses.